# Conversão de número inteiro para preço usando QLocate

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso usar `QLocate` para converter número inteiro em forma padrão de preço brasileiro
(sem arredondamento dos valores)?

Código:

```
QString n1 = "1.020,50";
QString n2 = "10,33";

int  valor1 = n1.replace(".","").replace(",","").toInt();
int  valor2 = n2.replace(".","").replace(",","").toInt();

int resultado_int = (valor1 + valor2);
qDebug() << resultado_int; //correto sem arredondar 100383

//converter
QLocale loc = QLocale::system();
QLocale brasil(QLocale::Portuguese);
loc.setNumberOptions(brasil.numberOptions());
QLocale::setDefault(loc);
qDebug() << brasil.toString(resultado_int); //erro return = "103.083"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque você retirou a ',' e o '.' para tornar um número inteiro.
Mas, quando você vai imprimir o valor final você não retorna com a parte dos centavos e 
a conversão acredita que é 103.083 reais e 0 centavos.

Para resolver isso, convertendo para `float` apenas no final:

```
QString n1 = "11.020,50";
QString n2 = "10,33";

int  valor1 = n1.replace(".","").replace(",","").toInt();
int  valor2 = n2.replace(".","").replace(",","").toInt();

int resultado_int = (valor1 + valor2);
qDebug() << resultado_int; //correto sem arredondar 100383

//converter
QLocale loc = QLocale::system();
QLocale brasil(QLocale::Portuguese);
loc.setNumberOptions(brasil.numberOptions());
QLocale::setDefault(loc);
qDebug() << brasil.toString(resultado_int * 0.01, 'f', 2); // Retorna 11.030,83"
```

Comment: Mas ae que está o problema. Tenta fazer soma `11.020,50 + 10,33` retorna `11.030,8` e não `11.030,83`.

Comment: Eu rodei o código que postei e tá retornando `"1.030,83"`.

Comment: é `11.020,50 + 10,33` com `1.020,50 + 10,33` roda sem erro.

Comment: Realmente, corrigi o código. Acho que agora tá certo. Mudei principalmente o `toString()`

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora funcionou. :)